# Linking an ID in one table to the ID for multiple fields in another table

Tags: mysql, webforms, linker, matching

Basically I have a table with unique id's for a username. I then have an html form that asks a user multiple questions. I want to link my unique id to a table that stores the questions, for example 'questions'. In 'questions' I want to link the id for the questions to the unique id for the username. So questions 1,2,3,4,5 for example, would have id's 1,1,1,1,1 for username 'Bob'. How can I do this? I've struggled with writing queries and have searched multiple sources but have had no luck. Thank you for the help

Answer (score -1):

Lets suppose you have following schemas

```
users
-----
+ id
- name

questions
---------
+ id
- user_id
- question_txt
```

use this query

```
SELECT u.id, u.`name`, q.id as 'question_id', q.question_txt
FROM
    users u
    INNER JOIN questions q ON u.id=q.user_id
```